# Is there any performance difference in using int versus int8_t

Tags: c, types, micro-optimization

My main question is, **Is there any difference between int and int8_t for execution time** ?

In a framework I am working on, I often read code where some paramteres are set as `int8_t` in function because "that particular parameter cannot be outside the -126,125 range".

In many places, `int8_t` is used for communication protocol, or to cut a packet into many fields into a `__attribute((packed)) struct`.

But at some point, it was mainly put there because someone thought it would be better to use a type that match more closely the size of the data, probably think ahead of the compiler.

Given that the code is made to run on Linux, compiled with gcc using glibc, and that memory or portability is not an issue, I am wondering if it is actually a good idea, performance-wise.

My first impression comes from the rule "Trying to be smarter than the compiler is always a bad idea" (unless you know where and how you need to optimize).

However, I do not know if using `int8_t` is actually a cost for performance (more testing and computation to match the `int8_t` size, more operations are needed to ensure the variable do not go out of bounds, etc.), or if it does improve performance in some way.

I am not good at reading simple asm, so I did not compile a test code into asm to try to know which one is better.

I tried to find a related question, but all discussion I found on `int<size>_t` versus `int` is about portability rather than performance.

Thanks for your input. Assembly samples explained or sources about this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is operating system, compiler, optimization, ABI, and target processor specific.

Comment: gcc on Debian, -std=c99 without -O2, 32bit i686 processor. I hope that clarifies a bit.

Comment: If you are looking for performance, the typedef int_fast#_t, with # replaced by the width, designates the fastest signed integer type with a width of at least # bits.

Comment: Do they say that performance is the driving factor? To me, the documentation value is important. The choice of an 8 bit signed value tells me that this parameter will be in that range.

Comment: Want numbers? Measure.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`int` is generally equivalent of the size of register on CPU. C standard says that any smaller types must be converted to `int` before using operators on them.

These conversions (sign extension) can be costly.

```
int8_t a=1, b=2, c=3;
 ...
a = b + c; // This will translate to: a = (int8_t)((int)b + (int)c);
```

If you need speed, `int` is a safe bet, or use `int_fast8_t` (even safer). If exact size is important, use `int8_t` (if available).

Comment: I thought those conversions would append at compile time rather than execution time.

Comment: @DainDwarf You cannot know what value variable has at runtime, so conversion must be done at runtime (excluding constant expressions).

Comment: Furthermore, there used to be a period of time when the manuals of the then-latest-and-greatest intel CPUs (early 386 if I remember correctly) clearly stated that many instructions accepting a byte operand would take one clock cycle longer to execute than the equivalent instructions dealing with a dword operand.

Comment: @user694733 in this simple case it may be calculated in compile time after optimization but in most case you can't simply do that in compile time except for constants. Write some functions using `int8_t` and you'll see it uses a lot of sign/zero extension to int and masking the type back to `int8_t`

Comment: @MikeNakis Not much different from today I guess: My ARM compiler manual says to avoid 8/16-bit types in favor of 32-bit types for these reasons.

Comment: @user694733 oops sorry, I intended to tag the OP, not you

Comment: Sign-extension can be optimized away within a function, only needed when used with an `int` or pointer.  It does depend on the ABI, though; some like x86 allow high garbage, so there can be zero overhead for `int8_t` https://godbolt.org/z/E3hx34 shows that for x86, but shows overhead for ARM.  Also that it does it inefficiently, clearing high bits of both inputs instead of after adding.  Also, some microcontrollers with only 8-bit registers need extended precision to implement 16-bit `int`.  (e.g. AVR).  So `int8_t` is much faster there.

Answer (score 1):

when you talk about code performance, there are several things you need to take into account which affect this:

- CPU architecture, more to the point, which data types does the cpu support natively ( does it support 8 bit operations? 16 bit? 32 bit? etc...)
- compiler, working with a well known compiler is not enough, you need to be familiar with it: they way you write your code influences the code it generates
- data types and compiler intrinsics: these are always considered by the compiler when generating code, using the correct data type (even signed vs unsigned matters) can have a dramatic performance impact.

  "Trying to be smarter than the compiler is always a bad idea" - that is not actually true; remember, the compiler is written to optimize the general case and you are interested in you particular case; it's always a good idea to try and be smarter than the compiler.

Your question is really too broad for me to give a "to the point" answer (i.e. what is better performance wise). The only way to know for sure is to check the generated assembly code; at least count the number of cycles the code would take to execute in both cases. But you need to understand the code to understand how to help the compiler.